# How to remove character from string using xslt?

Tags: xslt

```
<Scheduled>
 <xsl:value-of select="//RequestParameters/Identifier/DepartureDate">
 </xsl:value-of>
 </Scheduled>
```

In this xslt code iam getting a last character as 'z' in "//RequestParameters/Identifier/DepartureDate" i want to remove z and please help on this.

Answer (score 3):

If the value of `//RequestParameters/Identifier/DepartureDate` contains 'z' only at the end, you can use [`substring-before`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before) function.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(//RequestParameters/Identifier/DepartureDate, 'z')">
```

edit:

If you want to get the first 10 characters of the value, you can use [`substring`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring) function.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(//RequestParameters/Identifier/DepartureDate, 1, 10)">
```

Comment: thanks snak. Here DepartureDate is of type date for eg value is 2011-10-16T09:40:00.000Z but i need in output(preserve) only ten characters i.e 2011-10-16.Could you please help on this?

Comment: You can use substring function for the purpose. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you may want to convert an element value in ISO 8601 date format to another format by adding a javascript function to your xslt, and call that function in your Xpath expression.
For instance, when you have added a (javascript) function `convertToDate` that extracts the date part of the input value in the format `yyyymmdd`, the Xpath expression

```
convertToDate (//RequestParameters/Identifier/DepartureDate)
```

will result in a value

```
20111016
```

assuming there is only one DepartureDate element in the input, having value

```
2011-10-16T09:40:00.000Z
```